# I need to use my variable of rows that i got from my controller, to send it back to another controller using Ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have a View to display a menu of categories and its products based on the authenticated user, which means I only want certain categories/products displayed, my problem is in the search bar when I type all products show from all categories but I want the search to only find products in those certain categories. That's why I tried to send with the ajax request a variable that contains a list of objects, these objects are my categories:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1381 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
   0 => App\Models\Categorie {#1385 ▶}
  ]
}
```

the problem is that ajax is giving me an error with my $categories variable, i don't know how to use this variable in my script i want to send the objects or a list of the object ids so i cant treat them in my controller using the WhereIn methode in my sql search request , here is my script :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    fetch_customer_data();
    function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
    {
        var data =[];

        $.each({{$categories}} , function( index, value ) {
            data.push(value->id);
        });
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('search') }}",
            method:'GET',
            data: {query: query, data:data },
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#result').html(data.html);
                } else {
                    console.log(data.message);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    $(document).on('keyup', '#keyword', function($e){ // define event parameter
        var query = $(this).val();

        fetch_customer_data(query);
        //$('#result').html(data.html); remove this line
        $e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and here is my controller methode :

```
    public function search(Request $request)
{
    try{
        if($request->ajax()) {
            $query = $request->get('query');
            if(empty($query)) {
                return back()->withError("Désolé, une erreur de serveur s'est produite (requête vide)");
             }
            else {
                $products =DB::table('product_categories')
                            ->join('produits', 'product_categories.produit', '=', 'produits.id')
                            ->join('categories', 'product_categories.categorie', '=', 'categories.id')
                            ->select('produits.*')
                            ->whereIn('product_categories.categorie',$request->data)
                            ->where([['nomProduit','LIKE','%'.$query.'%'],['categories.visibilite','=',1],['produits.visibilite','=',1]])
                            ->orWhere([['typeActivite','LIKE','%'.$query.'%'],['categories.visibilite','=',1],['produits.visibilite','=',1]])
                            ->get();

            }
            $total = $products->count();
            $html = view('front.search_result', [
                    'products' => $products,
                ])->render();


            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'html' => $html,
                'total' => $total,
            ], 200);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => "Oups! quelque chose s'est mal passé !",
            ], 403);
        }
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
        Alert::error('Erreur ', $e->getMessage())->autoClose(false);
        return redirect()->back();
    }catch (Error $e) {
        // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
        Alert::error('Erreur ', $e->getMessage())->autoClose(false);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

and the type of the variable $categories is :

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1381 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => App\Models\Categorie {#1385 ▼
    #fillable: array:4 [▶]
    #files: array:1 [▶]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: "categories"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    +preventsLazyLoading: false
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "parent_id" => null
        "categorie" => "Informatique"
        "description" => "informatique"
        "photo" => "categories/Informatique .jpg"
        "visibilite" => 1
        "deleted_at" => null
        "created_at" => "2021-04-19 06:33:16"
        "updated_at" => "2021-08-07 14:06:45"
      ]
  #original: array:9 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

]
}

and finally here is the error :
[image: Error at the console]

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to `{! json_encode($categories) !}`

Comment: i'm not using any javascript when i used ur answer it gave me the error  :Uncaught ReferenceError: json_encode is not defined, and here is how i used your answer é var data =[];
            var cats = json_encode($categories);
            $.each(cats , function( index, value ) {
                data.push(value.id);
            });  if you want me to encode the $categories at my controller i can't because i'm using this variable mainly in my view to display the categories menu then i want to passs those categories to another controller using that ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

Got it !
here is how it worked for me :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    fetch_customer_data();
    function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
    {
        var data =[];
        var cats = @json($categories->toArray());
        console.log(cats);
        $.each(cats , function( index, value ) {
            data.push(cats[index].id);
        });
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('search') }}",
            method:'GET',
            data: {query: query, data : data},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $('#result').html(data.html);
                } else {
                    console.log(data.message);
                }
            }
        })
    }
    $(document).on('keyup', '#keyword', function($e){ // define event parameter
        var query = $(this).val();

        fetch_customer_data(query);
        //$('#result').html(data.html); remove this line
        $e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

and didn't change nothing in my contorller i sent the $categories using compact